# Speeding up 10000x reads (exactly same data) from DynamoDB to Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have the following question. I have a Lambda function that performs some calculations. In order to achieve this it queries some data from DynamoDB (it is always exactly the same data) around 3 MB in size.

I would like to do this simultaneously in a few thousand instances at the same time. How can I speed this up a lot, without paying insanely much?

Thanks!

Comment: I don’t know what you budget is, but you could look into using DAX to cache in front of DynamoDB.

Comment: What is exactly what you want to do? Improve the availability of the reads? Or run the calculations multiple times in parallel?

Comment: @MatthewPope That is a possibility, but it just adds so much overhead as I need a VPC, extra clusters for DAX and configure to be able to communicate with it from outside of VPC.

Comment: @guzmonne 

I am running 10000 calculations in parallel, they are all starting with the exact same data, which I'd like to load. Calculations themselves are relatively fast (5-15 seconds).

Comment: Can you put the starting data in S3? It can handle thousands of parallel requests.

Comment: So, what you want is to create a Serverless Iterator. You call one Lambda function and trigger several other Lambdas that will do some work in parallel. The best way I know to do this is by using Step Functions. Here is a link with details of how to create an Iterator using Step Functions: [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-create-iterate-pattern-section.html](Iterating a Loop Using Lambda)